# objective c group array

Tags: objective-c

I have array like this:

```
{
    toNumber = +79995840405;
    type = 9;
}
{
    toNumber = +79995840405;
    type = 65;
}
{
    toNumber = +79995840405;
    type = 9;
}
{
    toNumber = +79995840405;
    type = 65;
}
```

How can I group items by toNumber & type? thanks

Comment: What is the expected resulting data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You have provided little detail, which makes it hard for people to help you; and haven't shown what you have tried yourself and explained where you got stuck, which is the SO approach - people here will help you, not do the work for you.

The above is why you are getting close votes.

That said let's see if we can point you in the right direction, but understand this is based on guesswork about what you have and your problem.

So it sounds like you have an array (`NSArray`) of dictionaries (`NSDictionary`) and wish to produce a dictionary of arrays. A straightforward iteration can be used for that:

1. Create an empty result dictionary (`NSMutableDictionary`)
2. Iterate over your array looking at each element (`foreach`)
3. Using the `type` value of your element as the key value of your result dictionary:

   3.1. If there is no entry in your result dictionary for the key create a new array (`NSMutableArray`), add the element's `toNumber` value to it, and add the array to your result dictionary.

   3.2 Otherwise simply add to `toNumber` value to the existing array at the key entry of your result dictionary.

That's it, each bullet is a line or two of code.

If you get stuck as a new question, providing details, showing your code, and explaining what you problem is. Someone will undoubtedly help you from there.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for reply I have json array like this:
   "items": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "src": "79135593313",
           "dst": "79222222222",
           "calldate": 1470375542,
           "type": "ANSWER",
      }
    ]
Right now all items loaded in NSMutableArray then to tableview with sections by date, I need group by toNumber & type, like in iOS phone application.

Comment: The data you give here is different than in the question, the problem description is also different, both are incomplete, and you have not shown what you have tried and why it didn't work. Open a new question, provide all that, and someone will probably help you. Remember on SO people help you sort out your solution, or nudge you in the right direction of a solution, they don't solve the whole problem for you. HTH